# Aggregate function within Pivot table query using SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot-table

I have a table as shown below with the details:

```
CREATE TABLE testrf
(
  cola INTEGER,
  colb VARCHAR(10)
)
```

Inserting some data:

```
INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(1,'x')  
INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(1,'x')
INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(2,'x')
INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(3,'y')
INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(4,'y')
INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(5,'c')
INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(6,'c')
INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(7,'c')
INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(8,'d')
INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(3,'y')
INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(12,'M1')
INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(13,'L1')
INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(14,'C2')
INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(1,'c')
INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(1,'d')
INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(1,'L1')


SELECT * FROM testrf;

cola   colb
------------
1       x
1       x
2       x
3       y
4       y
5       c
6       c
7       c
8       d
3       y
1       c
1       d
12      M1
13      L1
14      C2
1       L1
```

Now I want to show pivot table for the above data for which I have written the query:

```
 DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX)
 DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

 SELECT  @cols = STUFF ( (SELECT DISTINCT '],[' + v.colb                        
               FROM testrf AS v                                         
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') + ']'   


SET @SQL = N'SELECT cola,TotalGroups,AvailableIn,'+ @cols +'
   FROM                     
   (SELECT  v.cola,v.colb,(select count(distinct colb) from testrf) TotalGroups,c.AvailableIn
       FROM testrf AS v  
       inner join
       (select cola,count(case when colb>=1 then 1 else 0 end) AS AvailableIn FROM testrf
       group by cola) c 
       on c.cola = v.cola                                                                                                  
    ) p                     
       PIVOT                
           (            
               count(colb)                        
               FOR colb IN ( '+ @cols + ' )                        
           ) AS pvt';      

    EXEC(@SQL)
```

I will get this:

```
 cola TotalGroups AvailableIn  c    C2  d   L1  M1  x   y
 ----------------------------------------------------------
 1       7            5        1    0   1   1   0   2   0
 2       7            1        0    0   0   0   0   1   0
 3       7            2        0    0   0   0   0   0   2
 4       7            1        0    0   0   0   0   0   1
 5       7            1        1    0   0   0   0   0   0
 6       7            1        1    0   0   0   0   0   0
 7       7            1        1    0   0   0   0   0   0
 8       7            1        0    0   1   0   0   0   0
 12      7            1        0    0   0   0   1   0   0
 13      7            1        0    0   0   1   0   0   0
 14      7            1        0    1   0   0   0   0   0
```

**Note**: Please note the `row number  1 and 3`. In `AvailableIn` column values are 5 for 1st row where the available values for the columns are 4 only that is `c,d,L1,x` rest of all are zeros. And also row number 3 where `AvailableIn` is 2 where available values for the columns is only 1 that is `y`. I think am stuck in `aggregate function` within the `pivot query`.

**SQL Fiddle**-> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1acc/8

Comment: You've got all the bits, it would be helpful to have a [sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: Please check SQL Fiddle.

Comment: there is a similar question to this recently, but I see it's different

Comment: @Used_By_Already,Nope! That was for TotalGroup issue. This is for `AvailableIn`.

Comment: @Used_By_Already, Yes this is different one.

Comment: @paqogomez, Exactly! But this is really strange for me that how `count(distinct colb)` works for both `TotalGroups` and `AvailableI`.

Comment: You are grouping by colb in the second one. Where the first counts them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than counting if `colb` is greater than 1 (which all your letters are), you want a distinct list (as you have in the parent query) of `colb`

Here was the only change I made:

```
(select cola,count(distinct colb) AS AvailableIn FROM testrf
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1acc/16)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there is a question?

```
INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(1,'x');
INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(1,'x');
...
INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(1,'c');
INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(1,'d');
INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(1,'L1');

That is 5 references to ColA = 1

c    C2  d   L1  M1  x   y
1    0   1   1   0   2   0  << adds to 5
```

There are some recommendations I would add to your query

1. to use QUOTENAME() instead of hard-coding the [ ] brackets.
2. ColB is Varchar so don't use WHEN ColB >=1, use COLB >= '1'
3. COUNT() adds one for every non-null value, so don't use `else 0` inside the count

   ```
   DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

   SELECT  @cols = STUFF ( (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(v.colb)                        
                  FROM testrf AS v                                         
   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 


   SET @SQL = N'SELECT cola,TotalGroups,AvailableIn,'+ @cols +'
      FROM                     
      (SELECT  v.cola,v.colb,(select count(distinct colb) from testrf) TotalGroups,c.AvailableIn
          FROM testrf AS v  
          inner join
          (select cola,count(case when colb>=''1'' then 1 end) AS AvailableIn FROM testrf
          group by cola) c 
          on c.cola = v.cola                                                                                                  
       ) p                     
          PIVOT                
              (            
                  count(colb)                        
                  FOR colb IN ( '+ @cols + ' )                        
              ) AS pvt'    

   EXEC(@SQL)
   ```